# After running "mkinitcpio -p linux" i got "Hook 'lvm' cannot be found"

Tags: linux, arch-linux, filesystems, system-installation, lvm

Trying to install Arch with LVM basing on this guide: http://sharpeend.impcode.com/2014/04/installing-arch-linux-with-lvm.html

Partitions:

```
sda
-system-boot
-systrm-root
-system-home
```

Comment: 1) You should only ever use the Beginners' Guide or Official Install Guide (and associated links) to install Arch Linux. Anything else is unsupported and likely radically out-of-date. 2) What do you have in your ``mkinitcpio.conf``?

Comment: You only need to install lvm2 after adding lvm2 in the right order at the hooks inside your mkinitcpio.conf file in /etc

Answer (score 6):

You need to install lvm2 (but I suspect you did this already, since you setup-ed your disks with lvm commands!?)

```
# pacman -S lvm2
```

Then add the `lvm2` hook to the `HOOKS=` variable in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`:

```
HOOKS="consolefont keyboard keymap base udev modconf block mdadm_udev encrypt lvm2 resume filesystems autodetect shutdown"
```

(my config, you won't need all of those, just add the hook before `resume filesystems autodetect`)

Then redo `$ mkinitcpio -p linux`